# Search on loads of ID's in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, prepared-statement

Is there a way to put this in one, or multiple FAST queries?:

I'm using PDO::MySQL

```
<?php
 $ids = array(1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 23, 24, 26, 28); // example, this can hold up to 1000 unique id's
 $results = array();
 $stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT a, b, c FROM table WHERE id = ?");
 foreach($ids as $id) {
   $stmt->execute(array($id));
   $results[] = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
 }
?>
```

Do I really have to loop the ID's and with that extending the base query so it shows as:

```
SELECT a, b, c, FROM table WHERE id = ? OR id = ? OR id = ? //etc
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you don't need to loop. The quick and dirty solution is this:

```
$ids = array(1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 23, 24, 26, 28); // example, this can hold up to 1000 unique id's
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT a, b, c FROM table WHERE id IN (?)");
$stmt->execute(implode(',', $id));
```

The recommended solution, however, is to load your IDs into a MySQL table, and then do a query with a JOIN.

Answer (score 2):

I think you're looking for the syntax

`... WHERE ID in (1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 23, 24, 26, 28)`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `IN` operator and `implode` to do this automatically for you. It's not faster than multiple `OR`s, but it does make your query shorter, and it's certainly faster than the multiple queries you have now.

```
<?php
 $ids = array(1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 23, 24, 26, 28); // example, this can hold up to 1000 unique id's
 $results = array();
 $stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT a, b, c FROM table WHERE id IN (" . implode(',', $ids) . ")");
 $stmt->execute();
 $results[] = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
?>
```